# In python, calling a module using os.system, then calling a python module based on that

Tags: python, bash, module

I am currently writing a python script.

The ultimate goal here is just to import pysam. But, to do this, first I import a suite of tools known as galaxy, of which pysam is one.

If on the command line I first load galaxy, then enter the python interactive shell, then import pysam, the import is successful.

But, my script is like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

subprocess.call("module load galaxy/galaxy", shell=True)
subprocess.call("module load ngs-ccts/tabix/0.2.6", shell=True)
import pysam

caddfile=pysam.Tabixfile( "/scratch/share/public_datasets/ngs/databases/CADD/v1.0/whole_genome_SNVs_inclAnno.tsv.gz" )
for gtf in caddfile.fetch(1, 100000, 200000):
    print(gtf)
```

to me, this seems to recapitulate what I do in the interactive shell, which works.

The script, however, errors and returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pysampracticer.py", line 7, in ?
    import pysam
ImportError: No module named pysam
```

why is it that the script fails to import it while the same series of commands will work on the command line then the python interactive shell, and how should I approach this to recapitulate the results obtained on the interactive shell?

Answer (score 1):

```
subprocess.call("module load galaxy/galaxy", shell=True)
subprocess.call("module load ngs-ccts/tabix/0.2.6", shell=True)
```

Loads the modules in sub-processes. It doesn't affect the current process.

Not only that, the two calls create two independent sub-processes. In the first sub-process,
the `galaxy/galaxy` module is loaded but not the `ngs-ccts/tabix/0.2.6` modue. In the second sub-process, the `ngs-ccts/tabix/0.2.6` is loaded but not the `galaxy/galaxy` module.